# Bootstrap datetime picker Cutoff at different screen resolution

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a mvc application where i need to use bootstrap datetime picker.it is working well but it cutoff from side at resolution of 800 *1280 and 768*1024.

view for page is

```
  <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">date of birth</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class='input-group date'>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.BIRTHDATE, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "date-picker form-control" })
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

--------Script-----

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker();

$('.date-picker').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

we are using datepicker.css and jquery-1.11.0.js ,bootstrap.css for this datetime picker.
Please provide solution to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying a lot finally i took jquery to make it work. Please review below code

First we will just handle resize event of window as below:

```
$(window).on("resize",function () {
    ApplyDatepicker();
});
```

Then we will handle datepicker orientation according to resolution:

```
function ApplyDatepicker()
 {
$('.date-picker').datepicker('hide');
$('.date-picker').blur();

if ($(window).width() >= 760) {
    $(".date-picker").datepicker({
        orientation: "auto right"
    });
}
else
{
    $(".date-picker").datepicker({
        orientation: "auto left"
    });
}

$('.date-picker').datepicker('update');

$('.date-picker').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});}
```

After applying this datepicker is automatically adjusting its position now.